# AutoResizeTextView after setting .setMaxLines to a new value, what do I need to call, so the screen updates?

Tags: android, fullscreen

The screen doesn't update if I change the value for .setMaxLines in an [AutoResizeTextView](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView/blob/master/AutoFitTextViewLibrary/src/com/lb/auto_fit_textview/AutoResizeTextView.java). It works, if I rotate the screen.
So, if I change .setMaxLines from 1 to 2 nothing happens, but if I rotate the screen, the text renders correctly using 2 lines.
How to to invoke a screen redraw, so it instantly shows the text using 2 lines?

I have tried to invalidate the view with:
fullscreenContentTextView.invalidate();
but without success.